# Can different types of variable scopes lead to memory leak in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-leaks

I'm facing memory leak problem in my node js app. I can't post the code here but I would like to know if these things can cause **memory leak**. This may help me know where I might be doing something wrong:

1. Local variable inside a function:

e.g.

```
function Foo(){
  var foo = {a: 'b'};
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Now, if I call this function in a POST **route**, it will declare `var foo` everytime. Does it frees memory or old `var foo` is still somewhere holding memory? Do I need to explicitly do something like `foo = null` in last statement of my function? (Note that foo is an object here. I would also like to know if it were an integer or string).

What I want to say is like this:

```
app.post('/home', function (req, res) {
    Foo();
    res.end();
});
```

2. A route

This may be similar to 1st, but still I want to know:

```
app.post('/home', function (req, res) {
    var foo2 = 5;
    res.write("Something");
    res.end();
});
```

With every request, do I need to do like this: ?

```
app.post('/home', function (req, res) {
    var foo2 = 5;
    res.write(foo2);
    foo2 = null;
    res.end();
});
```

Or will it automatically free it?

3. If you see 2nd point, `req` is unused here. Do I also need to **null** or (something like this) it to prevent memory leak?
4. Global variable:

   var globalVar = 5;
   app.post('/home', function (req, res) {
       glbalVar = globalVar + 1;
       res.write("Something");
       res.end();
   });

Here, the only difference between 4 and 2 is scope of variables. Do I need to **null** this variable or overriding itself frees up memory?

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I read the other answer on original question by T.J. Crowder. It cleared some things to me but I still have doubt about my point 3 and 4. In 3, `req` object is NOT created by me so do I need it to make `null` ? In 4, the variable is global. Will it follow the same thing as told by T.J?

Now, as some things are cleared, I am adding one more situation here, which is I'm using [node-apn](https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn) in my script and has following async code block:

```
apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken).then( (result) => {
  // see documentation for an explanation of result
});
```

How I call this is like so:

```
app.post('/home', function (req, res) {
    var data = {foo: req.body.bar};
    // above object has all data required to send push notification
    sendNotification (data);
    res.end();
});

function sendNotification(data){
  //other lines of code
  //I use data to get note, deviceToken
  apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken).then( (result) => {
      console.log(result);
  });
}
```

Now my other question is: Is this example of closure as told by T.J? And since I have ended `res` before waiting for the response of my notification async function, will this **closure** (if it is), lead to memory leak as it will hold my `data` object?

Comment: Can you pinpoint exactly what is causing the memory leak - such as with a heap snapshot or allocation profile/timeline? A single variable is not the cause.

Comment: I'm gonna close this now; if you still need anything please [edit] and/or ping me.

Comment: @BenRondeau I don't know how to study the heap dump (I have created but no idea what it means. I tried to explore it after loading it in chrome but that seemed beyond my understanding.) If you want to see, I can show you dump.

Comment: @Bergi I will first try the other answer and will see if it clarifies my doubts. I will edit it if needed and will inform you here.

Comment: @Bergi please check now. I have edited my question.

Comment: Re #3: It doesn't matter who created the object `req` refers to. What matters is: Do any references to it survive? If so, the object isn't cleaned up (something is still using it). If not, it is. It doesn't matter whether you set `req` to `null` or not, because `req` is a parameter, and gets cleaned up when the function returns *unless* you create a closure within your callback that survives after your callback returns.

Comment: Re #4: The *variable* `globalVar` will exist as long as your module exists (it's not a global, it's a module-global). I don't think modules are ever *un*-loaded in Node but I don't know that for sure. If your module were unloaded, then the memory allocated to the module (including `globalVar`) would be reclaimed.

Comment: What callback are you referencing to? The callback that is returned by push notification code? Or the default callback in POST route?

Comment: 3 and 4 cleared my doubts. Can you say something about my EDIT?

Comment: Re #4: Yes, by overriding the global variable the old value gets garbage-collected, but the new value is of course still held in global memory. The memory of the variable itself is never freed - another reason why not to use global variables. Re #5: no, there is no closure in your code - none of the functions close over free variables.